# Flask + Socketio - How do I join a room inside a route (not inside a socketio function)

Tags: flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm having trouble understanding why my following code does not work. When the user logs in, I want to create a room based on that user's email. I tried two different ways. The first, I tried calling join or join_room, both of which did not work. When I tried `socketio.join(email)`, I got an error saying that socketio doesn't have a join and when I tried `socketio.join_room(email)`, I also got an error.

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
   def login():
      ...
      if userisloggedin:
         socketio.join(email) # OR socketio.join_room(email)
```

The second way I tried was to emit from the function and create the room separately:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
   def login():
      ...
      if userisloggedin:
         socketio.emit("privatemsg", email, namespace="/messages") 
 
@socketio.on("privatemsg", namespace="/messages")
   def gotMessage(email):
      print("JJJJJJJ")
      socketio.join_room(email)
```

When the user logs in, the server should print "JJJJJJJ", but it doesn't show up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure a client to receive the `privatemsg` emit event and subsequently emit it back to the server but a callback serves this purpose best

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    ...
    if userisloggedin:
        socketio.emit("privatemsg", email, callback=gotMessage, namespace="/messages") 
 
def gotMessage(email):
    print("JJJJJJJ")
    socketio.join_room(email)
```

on your client side do this:

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('privatemsg', (email, gotMessage) => {
    gotMessage(email);
});
```